# downloading missing python modules

Tags: python, module

Trying to get started with Python, have some experience with HTML, PHP and a couple of scripting languages.  I downloaded Python 2.7 onto my computer and seems to be working but I find I'm missing some modules.  Math, path, datetime and OS for sure, and trying to find out how to acquire them has been confusing at best so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Tom

Comment: They come along with python. How you know they are missing? FYI, you need to firstly import them before using them. For example: `import datetime`, `import math`, etc

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the path module, those should come with Python. Just put `import os` (or whatever other module) at the top of your script. To install path, open your terminal and use `python -m pip install path.py`.

If you don't have pip installed, look up how to install that for your specific OS.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I type import math I'm told that 'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Other commands and .py files run fine, and I was able to use the random module in a small .py file script and it ran fine.

Comment: `import <module>` should be within your python script. You can also just open a terminal, type `python` to launch the interpreter and use `import <module>` there.